# Set of elements which occur at least n times in a multiset.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a multiset $S$, in which elements $s$ occur. Each element $s_i$ occurs $m_i$ times.

How can I write a set $F \in S$, which is the set of elements $s$ which occur at least $n$ times in $S$?

For example: $ S = \{a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c,d\}$, with n = 3, $F = \{b,c\}$

I tried using cardinality to come up with the following:

$F = \{s||s| \geq n \}$

but I don't think this is right (next to looking ugly with the double $|$)

Does

$F \subseteq S, |s| \geq n \;\forall\; s \in F$

work?

Comment: Either [Multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) or sequences??? With multiset $A=\{ a, a, a, b, b,  \}$ element $a$ has *multiplicity* 3; in this case we have e.g. $\text {mult}_A=3$.

Comment: (1) In a Set , elements can not occur multiple times. Hence , your Issue is not well Defined (2) Even with that , F is not well Defined because it is not referring to S (3) Might be useful to include Some Example Sets in your Post to let us know what you want (4) If you think Double "||" looks ugly , then you can change "|s|>n" to "n<|s|" to avoid that

Comment: Better to say "$s_i$ occurs $m_i$ times".  Do you want $F$ to have the relevant $s_i$ once each or $m_i$ times each?  For the former, you would have $F=\{s_i \mid m_i\ge n\}$

Comment: I edited the question to try to incorporate all of your feedback.

Comment: @Henry That seems to be what I mean. Would it be possible to write this somehow without $m_i$? (E.g. by somehow using cardinality?) I think that would make more sense for the piece I'm writing.

Comment: If you use `\mid` or `:` then  $F=\{s_i \mid |s_i|\ge n\}$ or  $F=\{s_i : |s_i|\ge n\}$

Comment: You can partition $S$ in multisets containing only one type of elements. In your example, $S_a=\{a,a\}, S_b=\{b,b,b\}, S_c=\{c,c,c\},S_d=\{d\}$ and then use cardinality: $F=\{i\mid n\leq\mid S_i\mid\,\forall\, i\}$ or something similar.

Comment: @Henry would $F = \{s : |s| \geq n\}$ mean the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

That notation of writing $|s|$ to indicated the number of times an element occurs in a multiset is something I've never seen before, and doesn't occur anywhere in the Wikipedia article on Multisets. What they use is a "multiplicity function", $m(s)$, or $m_S(s)$ if you want to show the dependence on the particular multiset.

And in fact, in that article they define the support of a multiset as

$$ Supp(A) = \{x \in U \mid m_A(x) \gt 0\},$$
which is very close to what you want to do. So I'd recommend writing your set as

$$ \{s \in S \mid m_S(s) \ge n\},$$

although it might be a good idea to explicitly call out "where $m_S()$ is the multiplicity function" - I don't think the notation and terminology for multisets is particularly well-known among mathematicians.